# Need help to open a new frame in a frame

Tags: java, user-interface

Have made a login that opens a picture if the username and password are correct. I doing it as a GUI, but the problem is that after I write the username and password and click on login nothing happens. The program works in the console (without the GUI)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginView {
private static final String IMG_FILE_PATH = "index.jpg";
private static final String USERNAME = "Hudhud";
private static final String PASSWORD = "123";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setSize(300, 160);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    placeComponents(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    final JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(userText);

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);

    final JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
    panel.add(passwordText);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    panel.add(loginButton);

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (userText.equals(USERNAME)&& passwordText.equals(PASSWORD)) {
                URL url = LoginView.class.getResource(IMG_FILE_PATH);
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setSize(300, 300);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
                f.add(label);
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            } else {



            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginView
{
private static final String IMG_FILE_PATH = "index.jpg";
private static final String USERNAME = "Hudhud";
private static final String PASSWORD = "123";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setSize(300, 160);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    placeComponents(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) 
    {

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    final JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(userText);

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);

    final JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
    panel.add(passwordText);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    panel.add(loginButton);

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            if ((userText.getText()).equals(USERNAME)&& (passwordText.getPassword().toString()).equals(PASSWORD))   
            {
                URL url = LoginView.class.getResource(IMG_FILE_PATH);
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }

            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You ain't the boss");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I get this error but I don't know how to fix it. When I write the username and password it skips the if statement and gives me the else statement even though the username and password are correct.

Comment: You are invoking the `equals` method on a grafical component, which uses the standard `equals` of `Object`. you need to compare `JTextField#getText` or `JPasswordField#getPassword` to the actual username or password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the docs, you'd see `JPasswordField` inherits `equals()` method directly from `Object`, which states:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

That is obviously not the case for a `JPasswordField` and a `String`. So, you have to compare the contents of `JPasswordField` with the given `String`.

If you look into the docs again, you'd see the usual way of getting text from some component that is used for inputing text, `getText()` is deprecated for security reasons. Exact reason has to do with the fact `String` is an object, and it will stay in memory until garbage cleaner kicks in, and that's not what we want. We want to remove the password from memory as soon as we don't need it, so the right way would be using char array over which we have a bit more control. The correct way would be:

```
char[] passwordInput = passwordText.getPassword();
if ((userText.getText()).equals(USERNAME)&& 
    (Arrays.equals(password.toCharArray(), passwordInput)) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else, e. g. inform the user about the error
}
Arrays.fill(passwordInput, '0'); //clearing out password from memory
```

Comment: Why can't write an else statement after 'Arrays.fill(passwordInput, '0');'

Comment: Else statement is tied to the 'if' ,so it should follow it immediately, leaving Arrays.fill after it. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 if ((userText.getText()).equals(USERNAME)&& (passwordText.getPassword().toString()).equals(PASSWORD)) {
```

You should use getText() method for comparing value. In you code you are using equals method of Object class instead of String class.

Comment: `JPasswordField#getText` is deprecated and shouldn´t be used.

Comment: Two issues with that: `char[]` is an array, and `toString()` would return junk, and second, if I got it right, you're reimplementing same weakness for which `getText()` got deprecated. See my answer.